# Automatic return types for function pointer arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, return, c++14, c++17

I'm creating a templated function that takes in a function pointer, although I'm trying to simplify the syntax a little further.

So far I have something like:

```
template< typename obj, typename ret, typename... args >
auto py_wrapped_func( ret (obj::*f)( args... ) )
{
    // Do some stuff with the function pointer.
}
```

The trouble is, sometimes the return type, ret, is crazy long. I'm wondering if there's a way to simplify this to something like:

```
template< typename obj, typename... args >
auto py_wrapped_func( decltype(auto) (obj::*f)( args... ) )
{
    // Do some stuff with the function pointer.
}
```

Obviously this doesn't compile - "decltype(auto) is not allowed in function prototype". Is there a better way to go about this?

I'm aware I could just template on the function type directly, but I'd  prefer to avoid having to write out the template function type when using the template, or using `decltype(&obj::func)`. I need the arguments `args` as template parameters to be explicit in the template anyway.

I'm guessing the compiler needs to know about the function pointer type explicitly, and not just the object and some arguments. Am I asking too much? Maybe I am?

Comment: Why do you care how long the return type is? Nowhere in the code you've shown did you need to spell it out. Show an example of an actual problem you feel you need to solve.

Comment: Obviously when I use the template, I have to specify the return type. In my scenario I have a `std::vector<std::array<std::complex<float>,GetArraySize()>>&` which just looks like rubbish embedded in that function template. This definitely does not help with code readability. It is an actual problem.

Comment: Why do you think you need to specify the return type when using the template? In what way does template parameter deduction fail to work for you? Again, show an example where you think you must spell out a long type.

Comment: Why not simply replace `typename obj, typename ret` with `class func` and then declare `func f` and pass it anything that supports `operator()`, including function pointers, functors, etc

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36459641/partial-template-type-deduction) question.

The arguments of the function cannot be provided via template parameter deduction, however the function can. A simple solution is to rearrange the template arguments as follows:

```
template< typename... args, typename obj, typename ret >
auto py_wrapped_func( ret (obj::*f)( args... ) )
{
    // Do some stuff with the function pointer.
}
```

Now the object and return type can be inferred from the argument.

I wasn't sure this would work with a variadic template argument on the left. However it seems to compile fine...

Comment: The return type can be deduced without problems, you don't need to rearrange any thing, the return type is part of the definition of the argument

Comment: Yea, as template parameter deduction goes from right to left, and the arguments `args` can't be deduced in my scenario, I need them as the first argument.

Comment: The answer to question you are linking states that "the ordering of the template arguments doesn't matter for deduction".

Comment: Although "Explicitly provided template arguments can only be provided from left-to-right". As `args` must be explicit in my case, it has to go first.

Comment: @Matt I didn't understood that you wanted to give the return type explicitely. Anyway, the compiler can deduce the return type without problems when a pointer to member function is passed, and the order or template parameter doesn't matter either because all of these parameters are deduced from a single argument. The only situation where parameter order matters is when passing them explicitely or when the deduction of a template depends on another, which must appear first: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e01f64ed1bd51b3